# How to append two variables inside Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have some data in Json. For example, consider `endtime=316`, `starttime=420`. So what I need is I want to subtract this data and display it in my html page. I am getting subtracted values in alert but not able to append this data to the html page using **jQuery**.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/QZ342/11/)**

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>         
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active">
      <div data-role="content" class="ui-content"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview" id="ball">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var content='';     
$.each(data,function(index,item){ 
  var count = parseInt(item.endtime)-parseInt(item.starttime);      
  content +=  '<li><a href="index.html"><img src="'+item.thumb+'"  class="userimage">';
  count += '<span class="secondsbox" style="position:absolute; width:28px; height:15px; background: #485ac8; margin-top: 54px; margin-left: -4px;"><span style="position:absolute; font-size:12.52px; margin-left: 5px; color:#FFF; margin-top: -1px;" id="secdisplay"></span></span>';
  content +=  '<h3 class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</h3>';                  
  content +='<p class="username">'+item.bombscount+'</p></a></li>';    
});
$('#ball').append(content);  
$('#ball').append(count);
$('#ball').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: You have commented out the jQuery.js script tag... have you tried your code with jQuery actually included in the page?

Comment: I was just about to point that out.

Comment: but there is a reference to jQuery mobile

Comment: jQuery mobile requires the jQuery library, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Just got it. You need to include the jQuery library. Check http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are appending `span` elements to a `ul`. That is invalid as only `li` elements are allowed under `ul`.

perhaps what you want, based on the comments in the html, is

```
content += '<span class="secondsbox" style="position:absolute; width:28px; height:15px; background: #485ac8; margin-top: 54px; margin-left: -4px;"><span style="position:absolute; font-size:12.52px; margin-left: 5px; color:#FFF; margin-top: -1px;" id="secdisplay">'+count+'</span></span>';
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/QZ342/12/

Comment: yes, but the span is inserted in the `li` element, not the `ul`.

Comment: i think my mistake is i did not mention '+count+' as u hav done in the script.

Comment: @madhukumar, yes one change i made was the `+ count +` inside the span, and the other was that you were putting that string in the `count` variable instead of the `content`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an HTML element and then appending that, like this:

```
$('#ball').append($("&lt;span>").text(count));
```

`$("&lt;span>").text(count)` will create a span HTML element that you can append to the children of the `#ball` element. It then sets the span's text to count.

Comment: Incorrect. The `append` method calls `.toString()` and will append it to a DOM element: http://jsfiddle.net/YgB2R/

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the `count` variable declaration outside the `$.each()` iterator as you are later calling it outside the loop otherwise I assume you will have an undefined error:

```
var content=''; 
var count = '';//Declare it here
$.each(data,function(index,item){
  count = parseInt(item.endtime)-parseInt(item.starttime);      
  content +=  '<li><a href="index.html"><img src="'+item.thumb+'"  class="userimage">';
  count += '<span class="secondsbox" style="position:absolute; width:28px; height:15px; background: #485ac8; margin-top: 54px; margin-left: -4px;"><span style="position:absolute; font-size:12.52px; margin-left: 5px; color:#FFF; margin-top: -1px;" id="secdisplay"></span></span>';
  content +=  '<h3 class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</h3>';                  
  content +='<p class="username">'+item.bombscount+'</p></a></li>';    
});
$('#ball').append(content);  
$('#ball').append(count);
$('#ball').listview('refresh');
```

And here you code is working just with upside not and no other changes: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/7y9A2/1/)

Comment: Saying do not work is not enough since I don't know what you are really expecting! I got my sample working just fine and even I can see output of your code.